# Read directory files in Windows

Tags: windows, rust

When I try to read files from a directory in Windows I get this error:

> Err(Os { code: 123, kind: Uncategorized, message: "El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos." })

I use this path "D:\3D\HDRI"

And this is my code:

```
use std::{fs, io};
use std::path::Path;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut folder_path = String::new();

    println!("Folder path:");
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut folder_path)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let path = Path::new(&mut folder_path);
    let files = fs::read_dir(path);

    println!("{:?}", files);

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
let path = Path::new(folder_path.trim());
```

The read_line method will put \r\n at the end of folder_path.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you!